# get all posts filtered by a specific user (as opposed to $user->posts() )

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have User and Post models, and can do e.g. `$user->posts()`.
But I would like to do it the other way around.

How do I create a local scope for Posts so I can do e.g. `$site->posts()->forUser($user)`

The below works:

```
// Post Model

public function scopeForUser($query, User $user)
{
  return $query->where('user_id', $user->id); // thanks @omar-esmaeel
  // return $query->whereHas('user', fn($query) => $query->where('id', $user->id)); // same, but more complicated + extra DB query

}
```

I have the feeling there is a more "Eloquent" way (and that I am missing something obvious), where I don't have to deal with comparing the `id`'s.

Similar to [comparing models](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#comparing-models) like `$post->user()->is($user)`.

**Edit**: Was hoping the comparison could be done on a higher level where I don't have to specify the 'user_id' == $user->id comparison (I try to separate the Model logic from the DB implementation)

Comment: Not sure why the restriction of "not comparing 'user_id' == $user->id" is in place. The `->is()` method also compares primary keys (and more)

Comment: Under water that's what how `->is()` works yes. But it is not exposed on the Model level: if the DB implementation changes (e.g. use different keys) I don't have to change the Model logic.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the code you have provided? And if you already have the user in the `$user` variable, why aren't you just using `$user->posts`?

Comment: Problem with current code? See post, in short: I was hoping not having to specify again how to compare two models and do the comparison on a higher level just like the `is()` method. Why not just use `$user->posts`? The preferred syntax describes more the intent of the command: for a site get the posts for a user. And mostly: the other way around would result in the same question, `$user->posts()->forSite($site)`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

```
public function user()
{
    return DB::table('posts')
        ->where('id',$this->id)
        ->join('users','users.id','posts.users_id')->get();
}
```

Comment: I don't want the user for a post, but: get all posts filtered by a specific user.

Comment: I have updated my answer @wivku, Is that what you want?

Comment: Thanks. Indeed shorter, but in the core leaves me with the same question. Was hoping the comparison could be done on a higher level where I don't have to specify the `'user_id' == $user->id` comparison (I try to separate the Model logic from the DB implementation)

Comment: I think you need to add this comment in your original question, so people would understand what actually you're looking for. and I hope you find your answer

Comment: That makes sense, done. Thanks!

Comment: I have updated my answer one last time :'D. check it out, hopefully, this one would work

Comment: Thanks again Omar. But that's actually a lower level instead of higher level.